# Current limiter circuit in voltage mode SMPS

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I have simulated many ready-made SMPS templates in voltage mode configuration? It is easy for me to understand and design my own configuration of some SMPS in current mode, but when I come to voltage mode, I have difficulties in the current limiter circuit that is used to limit the maximum current through the inductor.

The current limiter circuit does not appear in the transfer functions of voltage mode SMPS, however I have noticed that the value of the shunt resistor and the maximum current selected have effect on the frequency response of the whole circuit.

As an example, let me present the following ready-made buck-boost converter:

[image]

I have varied the GAIN of Current controlled current source (CC-CS), and I have noticed that the system is stable for **60m ohm < Ri< 480m ohm** where **Ri** is the gain of the **CC-CS**

My question is:

1. How to go from theory to practice in designing this part of circuit?
2. How to choose the value of **Ri** and the values of the filter composed of R4 and C2 in the circuit, and what parameters affect the selection or calculation of this part of circuit (Current limiter).
3. How does this circuit contribute positively or negatively in the frequency response the open loop of this converter or other converters?

Comment: This is a quasi-schematic, with some functions (groups of parts) represented as simple symbols. The current sense transformer needs R2 to be 1.00 ohms, as it is its burden resistor. Many parts used to define loop gain of op-amps are not shown. They show voltage set resistors and loop dampening parts in detail, but not much else. It could be that the full schematic is proprietary and not available to the public.

Comment: Root Locus , Bode and other methods are used to determine optimal gain

Comment: This is a voltage-mode control type of circuit. The circuit involving \$R_i\$ is silent during the ac simulation and the value of \$R_i\$ has no effect on the power stage response. It is there only to limit the peak current in case of over-load or fault. The peak value is set by \$V_2\$ which is 1 V. With a 250-m\$\Omega\$ sense resistance, the maximum current is 4 A. As long as the switch current does not exceed 4 A, this section is mute during operations.

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes, this is what I have expected first, but when I have set Ri=0, just for curiosity, to deactivate the current limit circuit, the system does not converge and I got a message error 5039 in simplis, which means the system is not stable, This is why I have asked this question !!

Comment: A zero-ohm resistance is usually forbidden in SPICE and probably SIMPLIS too. Set it to 1u or so if you want to disable the circuit. But the easiest and safest way is to disconnect the second OR input which goes to the current limit and ground it.That way, only the PW modulator is alive.